# Setting default value of Radiobutton in License Agreement Dialog Box

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

```
I want to change the default value set in the License Agreement Dialog while 
installing.

Right Now, the default value of License Agreement Dialog is "I accept ....."
and i want to change it to "I do not accept....", so that each time the
installer run the default value of Radio button is set to "I do not accept".
```

This is windows installer build using Installshield.

Comment: What version, edition and project type of InstallShield are you using?

Comment: Version :- 2012 ; Edition :- Professional ; Project Type :- *.ism

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the Radio button group name. This can be seen when you select the 'Behavior' option (under your dialog box in User Interface-Dialogs in INstallation Designer) and check for RadioButtonGroup Type. Then you need to go to the Property Manager and type the desired value to that property. If you want "I Accept..." as default, then the value should be 'Yes'.